# How to get the first Test Run ID of the Test Case in Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

There is business requirement to display the actual start date of test case.
We can get the last run id from the test case object and details can be retrieved with the below query.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{lastTestRunid}/results/{lastResultid}&api-version=5.0-preview.5
```

Is there a way to get the first run ID of the test case?

Answer (score 0):

To get all id's take a look here [Runs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.1
```

Isolate the element you need and take the **id** for your `get test run by id` call.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{id}/results?api-version=5.1
```

Json Element (contains all tests, each have a `startedDate`):

```
json.value[0].startedDate
```

Output:

> 2019-07-30T10:24:16.697Z

Comment: Need the link between run Id and test case id to isolate the run id which is needed.
Basically I want to identify the run ids based on test case id.

Comment: You have the **test case id** from `_apis/test/runs/{id}/results?` and want the **run id**  `_apis/test/runs` ?

Comment: Thank you for your support.
I have a test case id.
"_apis/test/runs/{id}/results? " - we need to identify this id which is belong to the given test case id.

Comment: @Srivani could you post a example of your `test case id` and the API/Url where you get it from?

Comment: I get all the test points from the below API url.

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/27642/Suites/136409/points?api-version=5.0-preview.2]

From here I can get testpoint ID also Test Case object with id , name , url .
So Need to identify all the test run ids under this test point or testcase ID. When we see test run object , there is test plan , but not test point or test case.

Comment: I think I understand now what you need unfortunately I have no experience with **Test-Plans**. Sorry, but I couldn't know that your question is related to **Test-Plans**.

Comment: if the test cases were run by running the test plan. Is not the test run for test plan as well as test case too? If this is the case, you can try [Run Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)