# how to get test runid to call azure devops rest api to Get Test Run By Id

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have to call this Azure Devops REST api which requires **runId** and what is this runid and how to get it

REST API ENDPOINT - GET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/get-test-run-by-id?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66063067/get-pipeline-specific-run-id) and [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57672415/how-to-get-the-first-test-run-id-of-the-test-case-in-azure-devops-api) links but it is not working & there is no clear way to get runid in Azure DevOps Pipelines.Even if i call [this end point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to get all runs results, how i would filter current running pipeline.

I need to get runid of the current running pipeline to invoke above REST API.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Run Id in the URL of the pipelines you’ve ran.
You can visit the select Pipeline section of Azure Dev-Ops below:-
***Pipelines > Select one Pipeline***

[image]

[image]

***Select any Pipeline from the Runs> you will find the runId in the Azure DevOps url like below* :-**

[image]

```http
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_build/results?buildId={runId}
```

If you want to call Azure DevOps Rest API to get the run ID by pipeline you can call the below endpoint:-

You can get the Pipeline in the url of your pipeline like below:-

```http
https://dev.azure.com/<organization-name>/<project-name>/_apps/hub/ms.vss-build-web.ci-designer-hub?pipelineId={pipelineID}&branch=main
```

[image]

**GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=7.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/%7BpipelineId%7D/runs?api-version=7.0)**

**Reference:-**
[Runs - List - REST API (Azure DevOps Pipelines) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)

Comment: You mean we can get runid by querying above rest endpoint with pipeline id, but how to get pipeline id in yaml pipeline?

Comment: You can make use of pipelineId: $(System.PipelineId) and steps:
- script: echo "The pipelineId is: $(pipelineId)" also refer this SO link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563230/how-do-i-identify-my-azuredevops-id-for-a-pipeline-in-ado-pipelines#

Comment: test run id is different than build id, build id in the above url is different than run id that we have to pass in https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{runId}?api-version=7.1-preview.3

Comment: Any insights here? - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/get-pipeline-specific-run-id/1331800